# bind gridview with one column having a checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview with one column having a checkbox. I want to bind the gridview to the datasource and check/uncheck checkboxes accordingly depending on the predefined status values; (1 for true and 0 for false).

This is my try:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cerrada">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CBCerrada" runat="server" Checked="<% if (Eval("cerrada").ToString() == "1") { %>true<% } else if (Eval("cerrada").ToString() == "0") { %>false<% } %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

But I get the following error: "Server tags cannot contain <% … %> constructs"

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect.  Please see the below example on how to map your values

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CBCerrada" 
              runat="server" 
              Checked='<%# (Eval("cerrada").ToString().Equals("1") ? true : false) %>' />
```

Comment: I still don't figure out how to bind the checkbox status based on the predefined values (0 for false and 1 for true)

Comment: Now I get the following error: "String was not recognized as a valid boolean"

Comment: I think his values are actually `0` or `1`. I doubt that you can parse them as boolean. You may have to use `int.Parse(Eval("cerrada")) == 1` or `Eval("cerreda").ToString() == "1"`.

Comment: @DavidM you can consider accepting this as an answer so that it won't be shown in unanswered list :)

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for checked property and you are missing # after %

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cerrada">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CBCerrada" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("cerrada") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I still don't figure out how to bind the checkbox status based on the predefined values (0 for false and 1 for true)